# Settings Unix-like cursor context in Windows

Tags: windows, cursor, mouse-cursor

For example in many Unix distributions, even if a window is not active (not clicked last), I can move my cursor over it and interact with it.  However with Windows, I have to click it first.  I would like to set Windows to have similar cursor behavior as that in Unix.

Comment: The word you're looking for is [focus (7)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/focus#English).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be looking for [something similar to what is described in this article](http://tweaklibrary.com/Hardware/Input_Output-Device/20/Enable-Active-Window-Tracking-to-Mouse-Movements/11079/):

> When the mouse is moved over an open window it automatically sets the
>   focus to that particular window. It does not bring the window to the
>   foreground of the open windows.
>
> Auto-raise a neat configuration setting is possessed by the X Window
>   system. If this setting's in effect, you don't have to click on a
>   window to bring it to the front of the window stack. Instead of
>   clicking, just passing the mouse over a window raises it. This takes a
>   little getting used to, but once you've made the adjustment you'll
>   find that it eliminates a lot of extra mouse clicks.